# How to search/filter a specific DataTables column from a select

Tags: jquery, datatables

Let's say I have two selects. Those selects are populated from the database.

I want the datatables search engine to run when the user selects an option.

For example, if the user selects the `Director` option for the `Position` select, that would be equivalent to typing 'Director' in the search input.

Here is a code example:

[LIVE DATATABLE DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/4/edit)

If I'm not mistaken I would need to modify the `DOM` and add some conditions when the change event is triggered.

I've been doing some research but haven't found anything. Any help will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, provide relevant ids to your select inputs. Like position and country.

Then add this to your code

```
  $('#position').on('change', () => {            
        DT1.search($("#position").val()).draw();
  });

  $('#country').on('change', () => {            
        DT1.search($("#country").val()).draw();
  });
```

Here we are listening to the change event of the select boxes and then pass the selected values to datatable search method and then refresh the database based on the response received.

I have also updated the code [here](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/10/edit).